# Homemorphism from $S^n$ to $S^n$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $S^n$ be the unit $n$-sphere($n\geq2$) and $X=\{a_1,...,a_k\}$, $Y=\{b_1,...,b_k\}$ be two finite subsets of $S^n$, does there exist a homemorphism $f$ from $S^n$ to $S^n$ such that $f(a_i)=b_i$ for $1\leq i\leq k$?

Comment: Yes, this is true. First prove it for one-point sets on the interior of the ball, with homeomorphisms that fix the boundary. Then prove it for one-point sets in a general connected manifold $M$ (use the previous result to do it locally, then see if you can figure out how to do it globally), using *compactly supported* homeomorphisms. Then use *this* result to prove it for $n$-point sets in a general manifold (no compactness necessary).

Comment: @Mike Miller  Thank you very much for your help.Use the pasting lemma, we can do it locally.  We can do this for the one point. What is compactly supported homemorphism?

Comment: Hint: partition the connected manifold into equivalence classes, $x \sim y$ if there's a compactly supported homeomorphism with $\varphi(x) = y$. See if you can use this to prove that there's only one equivalence class. (I think this should be enough hints to get you on your way, so I won't comment further.)

Comment: @MikeMiller I will try. Thank u for your help

Answer (score 7):

One way to show this is the following.  Let $X\subseteq (S^n)^k$ be the set of $k$-tuples of distinct points.  Since $n>1$, it is not hard to see that $X$ is connected (you can draw a path from one $k$-tuple to another by moving only one point at a time, since the complement of any finite subset of $S^n$ is path-connected).  Now show that for any $a=(a_1,\dots,a_k)\in X$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $a$ in $X$ such that for any $b=(b_1,\dots,b_k)\in U$, there is a homeomorphism $f:S^n\to S^n$ such that $f(a_i)=b_i$ for each $i$ (by separating the $a_i$ with small balls, it suffices to show that a closed ball has a homeomorphism fixing the boundary and sending the center to any other point in the interior).  That is, each orbit of the homeomorphism group of $S^n$ acting on $X$ is an open subset of $X$.  Since $X$ is connected, there must be only one orbit.

More generally, this argument works with $S^n$ replaced by any connected manifold of dimension $>1$.

Comment: Actually it's kinda hard to see the connectedness of $X$, at least to me: It doesn't work with $n=1$.

Comment: @QuangHoang: Indeed, the theorem we want to prove is false with $n=1$! We're removing a set of codimension $n$, which preserves connectedness when $n > 1$.

Comment: so actually the way you have proved this, here if we replace $S^n$ by any connected $n>1$ dim manifold, then also this will work

Comment: @Anubhav.K: Yes, that's right.