# Given three arbitrary points in the euclidean plane, is there a way to homeomorphic map the plane so that the points become colinear?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $p,q,r \in\mathbb{R}^2$. Is there a homeomorphism $h:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $h(p),h(q),h(r)$ are colinear? I'm interested in whether such an $h$ be found for $n$ points in the plane, but perhaps I can figure that out from the $n=3$ case.

(Disclaimer: this question is relevant to a question on exam I had in a previous class, which ended weeks ago.)

Comment: Given any $n$ points in the Euclidean plane, there is a homeomorphism taking these to any other set of $n$ points. As a special case, the answer to your case is yes.

Comment: The set of self-homeomorphisms of the plane is $n$-transitive, for every $n$. This means, given any pair $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ and $(y_1,y_2,y_3,\dots,y_n)$ of sequences of distinct points on the plane, there is a homeomorphism that sends $x_i$ to $y_i$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Homemorphism from $S^n$ to $S^n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1514690/homemorphism-from-sn-to-sn) (not literally a duplicate, but the answer to this question follows immediately from my answer there)

Comment: @EricWofsey But in $\mathbb R^2$ there is such a nice and concrete answer as below... special cases have their merit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think when $n = 3$ the argument can be made quite a bit simpler, so because you want an argument that can be generalized, I'll go straight to $n$.

Pick a coordinate system in the plane so that the $y$-axis is not parallel to any of the lines through two of the points.

Let the points be $(x_1,y_1), \dots, (x_n,y_n)$. Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function whose graph passes through all $n$ points. Then $h \colon (x,y) \mapsto (x,y - f(x))$ is your required homeomorphism.