# $S^2$ without $n$ points is homeomorphic to $S^2$ without $m$ points if and only if $n = m$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, spheres

> Consider the unit sphere $S^2$ with the subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Now let $n,m$ be positive integers. Prove that $S^2$ with $n$ different points removed from it is homeomorphic to $S^2$ with $m$ different points removed from it if and only if $n = m$.

Let's assume that the $n$ points removed are $A = \{a_1, \cdots, a_n \} \subset S^2$ and that the $m$ points removed are $B = \{b_1, \cdots, b_m \} \subset S^2$.

First, assume that $n = m$. Using the stereographic projections, $S^2 \setminus A$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$ without $n-1$ points and $S^2 \setminus B$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$ without $m-1$ points. Since $n = m$, I assume that $\mathbb{R}^3$ without $n-1$ points is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$ without $n-1$ (possible different) points, but I don't know how to explicetly prove this.

If $S^2 \setminus A$ is homeomorphic to $S^2 \setminus B$, then, using again the stereographic projection, if $n \neq m$, then I assume that $\mathbb{R}^3$ without $n-1$ points is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$ without $m-1$ points, but again, I don't know how to prove this.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1514690/homemorphism-from-sn-to-sn for one direction.  The other direction is very difficult without some tools of algebraic topology; what tools do you have available?

Comment: $\pi(S^2\setminus\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\})$ is the free group of rank $n$, and the fundamental group is preserved under homeomorphism. @EricWofsey's linked answer shows the other direction.

Comment: @EricWofsey Oh, I did not expect this. This was an exam question I found in an older exam from my topology course. The difficult direction was indeed labelled as a "bonus exercise", so I assumed that it is doable without algebraic topology.

Comment: Oh, I guess you can prove it using ends, without any algebraic topology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1514734/86856), there is a homeomorphism $f:S^2\to S^2$ which maps any $n$ distinct points to any other $n$ distinct points.  Restricting this map to the complement of the $n$ points proves the reverse direction of your question.

The forward direction is easy with a bit of algebraic topology--for instance, the Euler characteristic of a sphere with $n$ points removed is $2-n$.  In the comments you mention expecting a proof without algebraic topology, though, so here is one.  Let $X_n$ denote $S^2$ with $n$ points removed.  Note that for any compact $A\subseteq X_n$, there exists a compact $B$ such that $A\subseteq B\subseteq X_n$ and $X_n\setminus B$ has exactly $n$ connected components.  Namely, let $B$ be the complement of a union of small balls around each of the $n$ points.  On the other hand, if $m>n$ then $X_m$ does not have this property: if $A\subseteq X_m$ is the complement of a union of small balls around each of the $m$ points, then any for any compact $B$ with $A\subseteq B\subseteq X_m$, $X_m\setminus B$ must have at least $m$ connected components, since there must be at least one contained in each component of $X_m\setminus A$.  Thus $X_m$ and $X_n$ are not homeomorphic for $m>n$, or for $m<n$ by swapping $m$ and $n$.

(In more fancy language, this argument essentially shows that $X_n$ has exactly $n$ [ends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_(topology)) and thus $X_n\cong X_m$ implies $n=m$.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why algebraic topology seems to be eschewed here, but for the harder direction I would guess that that $H_1(X)\cong\Bbb Z^{n-1}$, whereas $H_1(Y)\cong\Bbb Z^{m-1}$.

For this one can use that $X$ deformation retracts onto a "rose with $n-1$ petals".